# How to Perform a Hardflip on a skateboard?

Tags: technique, skateboarding

This trick is slowly becoming my nemesis... taking over the elusive Tre Flip, I think I have the foot placement correct with my back foot in the centre of the tail ready to swipe out ahead of me and my front foot very close to my back tilted to point towards the nose.

How do I ensure the board flips completely?

Comment: Does this movie answer your question? http://www.how2skate.com/forum/29316.htm I am not sure.

Comment: @NathanTaylor Link-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/q/190/527) here as links may die. Therefore, suggesting to explain the link in more detail (ie, the user's own words) will help you, the user who answers, and the community as a whole. See the [help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.

Comment: I want advice for flip tricks and grinds.
I have [Evolve](http://www.evolveskateboards.com/) **Electric Skateboards**. I have seen the video. But, don't know how to do flip and grinds. Video link - https://vimeo.com/74673448

Comment: flips on those boards would be nia on imposable with the size of the wheels and the positioning of the board between them as for grinds the wheels would probably stop you grinding completely also those off terrain boards are mostly used for speed skating and hill jamming if theres a way to flip or grind on them id be happy to see it

Comment: There's additionally various types of skating you can do. You have [Learn How To Skateboard](http://chicagoskateboardinglessons.info/), which is the place you predominantly skate on little inclines and do flip traps and toils, and after that you have vert skating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have had a breakthrough with this trick and have landed a fair few. the method is all in the back foot but your front foot has to be practically pointing forward and quite far back on the board swipe the front foot out to the side and push your back foot away from you out in front as hard as you can. its should spin up and through your legs almost like an impossible.

[image]I

Answer (score 5):

I've searched the internet and found some really good "How To's".

Here's a list of video instructions:

1. [Wade Desarmo](http://skateboarding.transworld.net/1000170186/videos/how-to-hardflip-with-wade-desarmo/), [0'34"], [0'52"]
2. [SkateCity](http://hkskatecity.com/en/article.php?id=28)
3. [VideoJug](http://www.videojug.com/film/how-to-do-hardflip), [0'16"]

and here's a picture by picture explanation on how to do a hardflip:

- [How to Do a Hardflip on a Skateboard - WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Hardflip-on-a-Skateboard)

Having watched a few videos, I think the following is key to initiate the flipping behaviour:

- the foot on the back of the skateboard is causing the board to lift. Upon lift, the other foot is touching the board, on the side, making it turn/flip. Watch closely how the first video shows the hardflip in slow motion at 52 seconds (press the play/pause button rapidly).